# DB2 varchar time select

Tags: sql, db2

I have time stored in the `MAJHMS` field as varchar like:

> 93601
>
> 112737

and I need to search

```
select * from table where majhms = 936
```

or

```
select * from table where majhms = 1136
```

but not full 6 symbols 112737

Comment: need where majhms > 936 and majhms < 1139

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `LIKE` expression, e.g. `select * from table where majhms like '%936%'`. LIKE filters based on a pattern.

Comment: Be careful with `%936%`, which would also match `193645`.  You would want to use `... majhms like '936%'`